# Excel Pivot Table - Percentage of a column

Tags: excel, pivot, percentage

I'm supposed to create a report with all the information I have collected about employees from certain departments. Im collecting their location, work mobile, work pattern and leave entitlement.
I have to also show the percentages of everything I have collected per object ( example: 76,22% Base locations collected from business services department.

This is currently what I have done:
[image]

The column highlighted in yellow is supposed to display for business services `(109/143) * 100 = 76,22%` so the percentage of base locations I have collected out of the number of reports. Is there any way I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

That's the calculated fields option in 'pivot chart' > Options

[How to on support.office](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/calculate-values-in-a-pivottable-11f41417-da80-435c-a5c6-b0185e59da77)

Then, it's just in the calculation field: one column divided by the other.